# Upload User Groups

Tags: deployment

1. What is the best solution to upload the many Public groups in Production?
2. And Share these groups on account level

Need to upload them from Full sandbox to Production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public groups can be created via change sets deployments.  Collaboration group members need to be created with a data tool such as SF dataloader.  Here is the official help doc

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004190&language=en_US